# Run program with build errors

Tags: c#, build, compiler-errors

This question might be a little bit weird, but I'd like my program to run with build errors. I am using windows forms (c#), and before initializing the main form, the program checks if I have Adobe Reader installed. This is necessary, because certain forms are designed to use Adobe's COM extension.

So I'd like my program to check at startup if Adobe Reader is installed, and if it is, continue, and if it is not, execute the supplied Adobe installer. My problem is that if Adobe Reader is not installed, the program won't even execute, so it can't even check for the installation, because it won't recognize certain parts of the code.

Do I have to use another program, which then executes the main one if Adobe is installed, or is there a workaround, so that I can use only the main application?

Comment: What do you mean "build errors"? Are you talking about exceptions you get during execution, or errors you get from the compiler?

Comment: I believe the tags hint that ;) I call them build-errors because VS refers them to as.

Comment: Yes, but I'm confused, hence my question. Surely, *you* have Adobe Reader installed so that you can build the program? As such, when you try to run that program on another computer, *you will not get build errors*.

Comment: Let me write it another way. If you get build errors, you do not even *have* an executable to run. So no, you cannot, and will never be able to, run a program with build errors. This is why I think that you're not actually talking about "build errors" as such. I think you mean something else.

Comment: Did Visual Studio compile your program? Do you have a .EXE file?

Comment: Yes, the point is, that what happens, if I run it on a computer that has no Adobe installed. Yes I have Adobe on the computer I'm using VS on, but I intend to use my program on other computers aswell. Are you saying, that it will execute even if adobe is not installed, and it will just throw an exception and crash when it reaches that part of the code?

Comment: I am saying that if it doesn't execute on that other computer *it is not a build error*. Whether it will actually execute or not depends on how you've referenced Adobe Reader. "Build errors" occur in Visual Studio on *your* computer. Runtime errors occur when you execute the program. If you've referenced Adobe Reader as an external DLL, it *may* stop the program from starting at all, but I think it would be much more likely it would crash when it tried to use Adobe Reader. Question: **did you try it?**

Comment: Let me be more clear. I said compiler-errors, because I uninstalled adobe a few minutes ago, just to experiment with the code, and how it works, what parts it won't recognize. I have compiled the code before, and I can't compile it after uninstalling Adobe. If I reinstall it, I can compile it again. But even if I create an .exe, will it run on computers without adobe, and just simply crash when the code containing the Adobe extension executes?

Comment: It depends on how you reference Adobe Reader. There is no way I can tell you what will happen. Why not try it? Install Adobe Reader, compile the program, uninstall Adobe Reader, start the program by double-clicking on the .EXE file (don't hit F5 in Visual Studio, this will attempt to rebuild it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this "solution":

The way I've worked around this problem (so that it will at least build) is to include the referenced DLL/COM object's (on the reference, choose to "Copy to Local" and set it to true).  Extract them to a folder and it *should* allow for you to at least build when the application has errors, since the references are available.  I've seen this used *extremely* successfully against COM object.

Say you have a "Common Libraries" folder in your solution's base directory, you'll navigate to the bin directory after you build the application on a machine with a good copy of everything that's needed (the COM object for Adobe).  You'll then copy the appropriate Adobe DLL's from that folder into the Common Libraries, remove the reference to the Adobe COM and then re-add pointing to the DLL's in the "Common Libraries" folder.  You may have to choose NOT to embed the types in the application (also part of the Reference properties).

The second part is to check for the application and determine its state.  I imagine even attempting to use the COM object without the application present should throw some kind of error -- and I've seen folks use try-catch blocks around to "fix" this.  That's not a great programming practice, so anything you can do to scan for it otherwise is better, but for quick and simple, try-catch generally will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using some kind of Launcher or Installer that checks for all the requested prerequesites before it starts your program.

I suggest you just add another application that checks for adobe installation and after the validation/installation is finished to start your own application.

Comment: Yes, of course I considered this (I was actually referring to a launcher at the end of my question), but I'd like to know if there is a workaround.

Comment: @zergerge to my knowledge no :(